# find number appears more

Tags: excel, vba

`1  2   2
4   5   4
3   3   3
0   1   0
1   2   2
4   4   3
4   5   4
4   5   4
3   4   4
3   4   4
4   4   4
3   4   3`

I have above three columns in excel,how to find the number that appears more times, for example, first row is 2 (because it has two 2 and one 1)

Comment: What do you want to happen in the case of a tie, i.e. each number appears once?

Comment: in this case, there is no result. this data is three people scoring on the quality of a produce, and if three people all have different scores then we cant make a judement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your layout is such that the first column is `A`, second column is `B`, etc., then you could put the following in cell `D1`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MODE(A1:C1)),MODE(A1:C1),0)
```

This also outputs `0` in case there is a tie. You can replace the `0` with whatever excel expression you want if you don't want ties to result in a `0`.

Comment: A use for mode! Seriously though, what a nice, simple answer.